# clang-format equivalent for PHP & HTML

Tags: php, html

From what I read clang-format is for c/c++/obj-c.

Which tool like clang-format would you recommend to automatically format/reformat PHP/HTML code in a consistent way? And why?

The use case would be to check code formatting in CI (continuous integration) when submitted through a 'pull request' for example.

If there is no such tool, how can we do this with clang-format?

Comment: "how can we do this with clang-format?" - **you can't**: Clang is not a HTML processor.

Comment: Also, it's practically impossible to consistently format PHP-and-HTML because in archetypical PHP there's so many criss-crossing concerns (e.g. "DB access in the middle of rendering a `<table>`? You betcha!") . You'll be better-off with sticking to a human code-review during PR review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can recommend [PHP-CS-Fixer](https://cs.symfony.com/) which is both a code standards checker. You can create your own ruleset or use existing rules. It can fix basic issues for you(locally) and can also be used in a CI to indicate rule violations. Here is an example of a github pipeline and config: https://gist.github.com/sixlive/2862a2185c76988838acaa45687a575c